# How to update E-mail, Address, Nickname, etc of a contact in Android?

Tags: android, contacts

Does anyone know how to do that? Even links to some tutorials would help.

I'm using a device with Android 2.1.

Comment: It has already eaten up four days, but you don't have the time to write whole sentences ...

Comment: I'm trying to say that if you already spent 4 days on this problem, then trying to ask a readable question could improve your chances of getting an answer. The amount of grammar mistakes and typos you had in your question makes it look like you invested no time at all.

Comment: If discouraging were my goal, I'd have simply downvoted or voted to close (both of which I didn't do). I'm trying to help here: Writing in clear, understandable grammar (and not using "u" instead of "you") will *definitely* help you be taken more seriously. I wouldn't be surprised if more than a few people skip questions with hard-to-read grammar.

Comment: @devA   please check answer i have update it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
i found it myself.. thanks everyone...  


public void updateContact(String name, String phone,ContentResolver cr,Activity a) 
    {

    String[] arr = {"DISPLAY_NAME","MIMETYPE","TYPE"};

    String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + 
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";
    String[] params = new String[] {name,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
            String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)};

   Cursor phoneCur = a.managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
   for(int i = 0; i<phoneCur.getColumnCount()-1;i++)
   {
       if(phoneCur.moveToNext())
       {
           String s = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
           String s1 = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(Data.MIMETYPE));
           String s2 = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
           if(s!=null)
           {
               Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@#############",s);
           }
           if(s1!=null)
           {
               Log.e("111111111111#############",s1);
           }
           if(s2!=null)
           {
               Log.e("2222222222222#############",s2);
           }
       }
   }

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();


        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, params)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "5657")
               // .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Sample Name 21")
                .build());
        String where1 = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + 
        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] params1 = new String[] {name,"vnd.android.cursor.item/name"};
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where1, params1)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Sample Name")
                .build());


        String[] params2 = new String[] {name,"vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2"};
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where1, params2)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "Hi There")
                .build());
   // phoneCur.close();

    try {
        cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 13):

Please check below link

[update contact details on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200436/update-contact-details-on-android)

---

**OR**

---

Create XML file "**editcontmain.xml**"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/EditContacts"
        android:onClick="@string/clickEvent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit Contacts" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And Create java file "**EditContMain.java**"

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EditContMain extends Activity {

    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
    private static final int EDIT_CONTACT = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editcontmain);

    }

    public void clickHandler(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.EditContacts:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                Log.e("c", c.getCount() + "");
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    String contactId = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    Toast.makeText(this, "ID = " + contactId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                    i.setData(Uri
                            .parse(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI
                                    + "/" + contactId));
                    startActivityForResult(i, EDIT_CONTACT);
                }
            }

            break;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw it.. but where will i set my values.. I'm asking coz i have never come across this way.. can plz tell

Comment: yes it is update existing contact. i have update email, name etc... i have checked it is working.

Comment: on which version of android it updates... I'm using 2.1.. sorry for too many questions.,.

Comment: no problem dude.. i have test it in 2.2 android emulator and i will check it on 2.1 android emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I was update my contact in email,number,first name and last name,and if email and number not have then add using `rowId` email and number also.

```
private void updateContact() {

        if (getRawContactId(contactId).length() == 0) {
            AppUtils.showToast(AddContactsActivity.this, getString(R.string.sorry_msg));
        } else {
            String name = etFname.getText().toString()+ " "+etLname.getText().toString().trim();
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

            String[] emailParams = new String[]{contactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
            String[] nameParams = new String[]{contactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
            String[] numberParams = new String[]{contactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

            ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation>();


            ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where, nameParams)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, etFname.getText().toString().trim())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, etLname.getText().toString().trim())
                    .build());


            if (categoryContactData.getContact_mobile().length() > 0) {
                ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(where, numberParams)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, etPhone.getText().toString().trim())
                        .build());
            } else {

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        //.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, getRawContactId(contactId))
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, getRawContactId(contactId))
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, etPhone.getText().toString().trim())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());

            }

            if (categoryContactData.getContact_email().length() > 0) {
                ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(where, emailParams)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, etEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                        .build());
            } else {

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, getRawContactId(contactId))
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, etEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                        .build());

            }
            try {
                cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
        //        Toast.makeText(AddContactsActivity.this, "Updated the phone number of 'Sample Name' to: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: and you get RowId using contact Id.

Comment: This answer is the most complete for the given question.