# How to Update Contacts Information in android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android.I'm developing a program which in i have 3 methods:

```
 1-FetchContactInformation() : read contacts id , name, number 
 2-ChangeContactsInfo():change names and numbers
 3-UpdateContacts(): it shoulde read the list from second method and update each        contact one by one.
```

I fetch contacts info in this method:

```
   private ArrayList<ContactInfo> FetchContactInfo() {
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<ContactInfo> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    Cursor readingContactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER },
            null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    contactList.clear();
    readingContactsCursor.moveToFirst();

    while (i < 3) {
        ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
        contactInfo.setContactID(readingContactsCursor.getString(0)
                .toString());
        contactInfo.setContactName(readingContactsCursor.getString(1)
                .toString());
        contactInfo.setContactNumber(readingContactsCursor.getString(2)
                .toString());
        readingContactsCursor.moveToNext();
        contactList.add(contactInfo);


        i++;
    }
    readingContactsCursor.close();

    return contactList;
}
```

but i don't know which class and methods i should use to update contacts.
any help really appreciate.
best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here [*how to change contacts info and update contacts*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530159/1889341) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465934/1889341), to fetch contacts info take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0), if you want more check that detailed [*android contacts tuto*](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/).